# CountIf column header matches day of week

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have a spreadsheet with a table containing multiple weeks, it has columns and rows like so:

```
             Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun Mon
```

1. User 1
2. User 2
3. User 3
4. User 4

A letter "H" will be enters for a users/day when they have booked some holiday, I need to count for each user the number of each days that they have taken as holiday.

I wrote the formula: `=COUNTIF(INDEX($N:$NMMATCH("Sun",$N:$NM)),"H")`

But this obviously it only returns a count for the first "Sun" column it finds and ignores all the Sundays after.

Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the range for user 1 is N2:NM2 and the headers are in N1:NM1 try this formula to count Suns with "H"

`=COUNTIFS(N$1:NM$1,"Sun",N2:NM2,"H")`

You can copy that down for all users

Answer (score 2):

Use COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIFS(2:2;"H";$1:$1;"Sun")
```

Now if you make a small table with Mon up to Sun as headers above it and refer to that for the 4th parameter you can ditch the "Sun"